# How to make api endpoint target user's localhost when deployed to Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, axios

I have this api which works fine when running locally. But, once it is deployed to Heroku i get a error 503 which is because it tries to target localhost on Heroku's server and not the user's localhost. Is there a way to make this target the user's localhost instead?

The frontend is React. Here's the code in React that fetches this api every 5sec.

```
axiosFunc = () => {
    const { user } = this.props.auth;
    console.log(user);
    axios.get(`api/avaya/${user.id}`).then((res) => console.log(res));
  };

  timer = (time) => {
    const date = new Date(time);
    return `${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}:${date.getSeconds()}`;
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.axiosFunc();
    this.interval = setInterval(this.axiosFunc, 5000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
```

**and this is the API on the backend with express**

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const xml2js = require("xml2js");
const Avaya = require("../../models/Avaya");
const User = require("../../models/User");

router.route("/:id").get(async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
  const axios = require("axios");

  axios({
    method: "post",
    baseURL: `http://127.0.0.1:60000/onexagent/api/registerclient?name=${user.username}`,
    timeout: 2000,
  })
    .then((reg) => {
      xml2js
        .parseStringPromise(reg.data, { mergeAttrs: true })
        .then((result) => {
          if (result.RegisterClientResponse.ResponseCode[0] === "0") {
            const clientId = result.RegisterClientResponse.ClientId[0];
            user.avayaClientId = clientId;
            user.save();
          }
          const clientId = user.avayaClientId;
          axios({
            method: "post",
            url: `http://127.0.0.1:60000/onexagent/api/nextnotification?clientid=${clientId}`,
          }).then((notification) => {
            xml2js
              .parseStringPromise(notification.data, { mergeAttrs: true })
              .then((result) => {
                const notifType = [];
                const notifDetails = [];

                for (let i in result.NextNotificationResponse) {
                  notifType.push(i);
                }

                const arranged = {
                  NotificationType: notifType[1],
                  ResponseCode:
                    result.NextNotificationResponse[notifType[0]][0],
                };

                for (let i in result.NextNotificationResponse[
                  notifType[1]
                ][0]) {
                  notifDetails.push(i);
                }

                for (let i = 0; i < notifDetails.length; i++) {
                  arranged[[notifDetails[i]][0]] =
                    result.NextNotificationResponse[notifType[1]][0][
                      notifDetails[i]
                    ][0];
                }

                for (let i in arranged) {
                  if ("Outbound" in arranged) {
                    arranged.CallType = "Outbound";
                  } else if ("Inbound" in arranged)
                    arranged.CallType = "Inbound";
                  else {
                    arranged.CallType = " ";
                  }
                }

                if (
                  arranged.NotificationType === "VoiceInteractionCreated" ||
                  arranged.NotificationType === "VoiceInteractionMissed" ||
                  arranged.NotificationType === "VoiceInteractionTerminated"
                ) {
                  const newLogs = new Avaya({
                    notification: arranged,
                  });

                  newLogs.owner = user;

                  newLogs.save();

                  user.avayaNotifications.push(newLogs),
                    user
                      .save()
                      .then((logs) => res.json(logs))
                      .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
                } else {
                  res.send("Nothing to record");
                }
              });
          });
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => res.status(503).json(err));
});

router.route("/history/:username").get(async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({ username: [`${req.params.username}`] });
  Avaya.find({ owner: [`${await user.id}`] }).then((user) => res.json(user));
});

module.exports = router;
```

**EDIT: I was able to fix thanks to @Molda
using fetch instead of axios doesn't result in cors error.
New frontend code**

```
  getLogs = async () => {
    const { user } = this.props.auth;
    const reg = await fetch(
      `http://127.0.0.1:60000/onexagent/api/registerclient?name=${user.id}`
    );

    let regData = await reg.text();
    let regxml = new XMLParser().parseFromString(regData);

    if (regxml.attributes.ResponseCode === "0") {
      axios.post(`/api/avaya/register/${user.id}`, regxml);
      console.log(regxml.attributes.ResponseCode);
    }

    let resp = await fetch(`/api/avaya/getid/${user.id}`);
    let clientId = await resp.text();

    let logs = await fetch(
      `http://127.0.0.1:60000/onexagent/api/nextnotification?clientid=${clientId}`
    );

    let data = await logs.text();
    var xml = new XMLParser().parseFromString(data);
    axios.post(`/api/avaya/getlogs/${user.id}`, xml);
  };

  timer = (time) => {
    const date = new Date(time);
    return `${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}:${date.getSeconds()}`;
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getLogs();
    this.interval = setInterval(this.getLogs, 5000);
  }
```

**New backend code:**

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const Avaya = require("../../models/Avaya");
const User = require("../../models/User");

router.route("/register/:id").post(async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
  const clientId = req.body.attributes.ClientId;
  user.avayaClientId = clientId;
  user.save();
});

router.route("/getid/:id").get(async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
  res.send(user.avayaClientId);
});

router.route("/getlogs/:id").post(async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);

  const arranged = {
    NotificationType: req.body.children[0].name,
    ResponseCode: req.body.attributes.ResponseCode,
    CallType: " ",
  };

  for (let i in req.body.children[0].attributes) {
    if (i === "Outbound") {
      arranged.CallType = "Outbound";
    }
    if (i === "Inbound") {
      arranged.CallType = "Inbound";
    }
    arranged[i] = req.body.children[0].attributes[i];
  }

  console.log(arranged);

  if (
    arranged.NotificationType === "VoiceInteractionCreated" ||
    arranged.NotificationType === "VoiceInteractionMissed" ||
    arranged.NotificationType === "VoiceInteractionTerminated"
  ) {
    const newLogs = new Avaya({
      notification: arranged,
    });

    newLogs.owner = user;

    newLogs.save();

    user.avayaNotifications.push(newLogs),
      user
        .save()
        .then((logs) => res.json(logs))
        .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
  } else {
    res.send("Nothing to record");
  }
});

router.route("/history/:username").get(async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({ username: [`${req.params.username}`] });
  Avaya.find({ owner: [`${await user.id}`] }).then((user) => res.json(user));
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: You can only make a request to the localhost from the browser in the user's computer. So the only way is to move part of the server code to the frontend.

Comment: the problem with that approach is that i won't be able to connect to mongoDB which is the wholepoint here.

Comment: Why it couldn't connect to Mongo? I never said move everything to frontend. The way i think it will work is: Make a request to your server to get data from mongo return whatever you need to frontend and make request to the localhost then send the result back to your server. Create another route on server if needed to process the data. You just gonna need to make a few more request to get the data back and forth.

Comment: ahh i think i got you now. i'll give that a try

Comment: I tried and now i am getting `has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.` When i am trying to send a get request to this 3rd party api `http://127.0.0.1:60000/onexagent/api/nextnotification?clientid=`

Comment: Well you need to look into documentation for the onexagent. I'm not familiar with its API.
Have you tried some simple request from command line? For example `curl http://127.0.0.1:60000/onexagent/api/nextnotification`

Comment: They have nothing about cors or headers in their documentation. I can access their api url just fine from the browers or postman, i'm getting a cross origin cors error with react though. I did some googling and it looks like i am out of luck on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't get the part of (requesting with Axios in API) 
Is this a third party API ?

But I suggest you to use (.env) which is a file in your root folder contains the development config like base URLs, expire tokens, API keys ... etc 
and when you upload to Heroku you have to make a (.env) in Heroku app and but your config 
 
Let's take an example

in my development mode, my .env looks like

```
app_url = localhost:4000
port = 4000
db = development_api
db_username = root
db_password = 
db_engine = mysql2
```

in my production mode, my .env looks like

```
app_url = http://appsomething.heroku.com
port = 80
db = production_api
db_username = root
db_password = 3210LDWAK@AALKQ
db_engine = mysql2
```

and read more about how to use [.ENV](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

Comment: Yes it is a 3rd party api. Basically it's supposed to fetch the call activity of the user and record it in mongoDB under their username. That information can then be used to automatically open or update tickets in freshservice etc..